# What should I do to import math.py that is not stdlib

Tags: python, python-import

I read the docs from python.org, but is still confused about this problem. In one project, I have the following script structure:

dir a:

```
    math.py containing func c()
    main.py containing main()
```

What should I do in main.py in order to import math under dir a rather than stdlib?

import math just does not work

Comment: Another option is to rename your file to something like "custom_math.py" or something that doesn't share a name with a module in the stdlib.

Comment: definitely agree with @SethMMorton. You may justify the name by saying "but it's only for this one project", but things have a way of growing, and if you're just learning you want to do things the right way, and that includes not naming modules after the stdlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edit:***

Sorry my mistake... This will never work. You can choose either to give your top level package a name that doesn't conflicts with a name in the standard library. Or the main script cannot be in the package directory. So basically you can either:

Rename your module to `my_math.py` and then `main.py` can be in the same directory and you can just do:

```
from my_math import c
c()
```

Or you make a package, for example folder name `test` (or any other name that doesn't conflict with a standard library package) with files: `__init__.py` and `math.py`, and in the same level as the `test` you create a `main.py` and then the code will look like:

```
from test.math import c
c()
```

Folder structure:

```
.
|-- test
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- math.py
`-- main.py
```

Comment: it does not work, unluckily. ValueError is thrown. ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Comment: Add an empty `__init__.py` to the same directory. That will make the directory a package. Though it's not a good practice to give your modules the same name, especially if they are top level modules, as a module in the standard library.

Comment: Also tried, but throwing the same error here. Does the Windows sys matters here?

Answer (score 1):

This CAN work.

```
sys.path.insert(0,'path/to/math.py')
import math
```

This will make python check at the specified directory BEFORE stdlibs. This is a risky method for the same reason. I would recommend putting math.py in its OWN directory and using that path, so nothing else is changed.

I would also recommend importing this LAST if you have other modules imported as well.

```
import stuff
import morestuff
sys.path.insert(0,'path/to/math')
import math
```

Again, using "math" is not recommended. Renaming is best, especially for popular modules like "math".

Answer (score 0):

You can import modules with exact specification of the path to the module file, and by giving the module a specific name.
Have a look at the [imp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) module.

Here's an example:

```
# file: math.py
def say_hello():
    print "Hello!"
```

and the main file:

```
# file: main.py
import imp
my_math = imp.load_source("my_math", "math.py")
my_math.say_hello()
```

given both files lie where the current working directory is, this works for me.

Note that this approach tends to be highly unmaintainable and unflexible. It is generally a good thing not to clash with standard library and other language feature names. Therefore, you should rename that module or move it to a (non-global) namespace, i.e., a subpackage.

For reference:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_source
- http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages